# Sharing the project, but not the code, with a tester

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Please forgive me if I am asking a dumb question, I am fairly new to ios and cocos2d programming. I have developed an app that is almost done. I have an architecture where settings are in a plist file.

I want to share the app with my colleague, who has agreed to test and make changes to the plist if necessary, so that he can see which settings are the best.

What I want to know:

**Is there a way to share my app with him (he has a mac and a ipad) so that he only has access to the plist file but won't be able to access the rest of the code?** Thank you in advance.

One idea: To put my plist on a server and have a call to download the plist file when the game begins, so he can just change that. Is there a better way ?

Comment: You can not change .plist from application bundle on device (you can with jail-break).
Yes, server-side solution is possible solution. Or u can implement some kinda settings section in you app. Or implement Settings.bundle. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, have the app download the plist so he can edit it on the server. When you save the .plist, save it in the documents folder (outside of the bundle). Bundle is read only, and modifying it will destroy the signature, making it so he can't install it, unless the device is jailbroken.

Alternatively, copy the file from the bundle to the documents folder on first run and enable file sharing for the app. Then he can edit the .plist file and update it via iTunes.

The bundle only contains compiled object code, so he will not have access to source code.

You can use testflight or email him the .ipa and he can install via iTunes, or if you have a developer account, you can set him up as a tester through iTunesConnect once you've uploaded your app.

Answer (score 1):

look for iExplorer, that should enable you to up and download resources to/from your iDevice.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a 'debug mode' (for example accessed by turning the phone upside down or whatever you like). That debug mode can contain controls to manipulate the settings read from the plist and reboot the game. No server involved, just client side manipulation so you can just hand him the binary.